# Javafx grid layout leaving big spaces

Tags: javafx, gridpane

I am making a text based game with a GUI. I am using Javafx I am trying to line up elements using grid panes. I am trying to making something like this:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAAIc.jpg).

Here is my code and what is looks like at the moment

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class test extends Application {

    Stage window;
    ListView<String> listView;
    TextArea descArea = new TextArea();
    Label healthLabel = new Label("Health:");
    Label manaLabel = new Label("Mana:");
    Label healthDisplay = new Label("100/100");
    Label manaDisplay = new Label("100/100");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Game");


        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setHgap(10);

        descArea.setPrefWidth(750);
        descArea.setPrefHeight(450);
        descArea.setWrapText(true);
        GridPane.setConstraints(descArea, 0, 0);

        GridPane.setConstraints(healthLabel, 1, 0);
        GridPane.setValignment(healthLabel, VPos.TOP);

        GridPane.setConstraints(healthDisplay, 2, 0);
        GridPane.setValignment(healthDisplay, VPos.TOP);

        GridPane.setConstraints(manaLabel, 1, 1);
        GridPane.setValignment(manaLabel, VPos.TOP);

        GridPane.setConstraints(manaDisplay, 2, 1);
        GridPane.setValignment(manaDisplay, VPos.TOP);


        listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.getItems().addAll("Action 1", "Action 2", "Action 3", "Action 4");
        listView.setPrefWidth(260);
        listView.setPrefHeight(150);
        GridPane.setValignment(listView, VPos.BASELINE);
        GridPane.setConstraints(listView, 0, 2);


        grid.getChildren().addAll(descArea, healthLabel, healthDisplay, manaLabel, manaDisplay, listView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 950, 750);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }
```

and it shows up like this
[example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHIJK.jpg)
I am trying to move the mana up under the health label and make the list box smaller. Is the grid the right way to do it or is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to move the mana up under the health label

Let the `descArea` span two rows. That will mean the two labels lie in one row each (rows 0 and 1) and the description area spans both rows:

```
// GridPane.setConstraints(descArea, 0, 0);
// (node, columnIndex, rowIndex, columnSpan, rowSpan):
GridPane.setConstraints(descArea, 0, 0, 1, 2);
```

> and make the list box smaller

You set the preferred size of the list box with

```
listView.setPrefWidth(260);
listView.setPrefHeight(150);
```

By default, the `GridPane` will resize each control to fill the width of the cell containing it. Since the list box is in the same column as the text area, which has a preferred width of 750, this will force the list box to also have a width of 750. You can fix this in two ways:

Set the max width of the list box:

```
listView.setMaxWidth(260);
```

or, if you prefer a "GridPane" solution, use some column constraints to override the default behavior:

```
ColumnConstraints leftCol = new ColumnConstraints();
leftCol.setFillWidth(false);
grid.getColumnConstraints().addAll(leftCol, new ColumnConstraints());
```

Comment: A small note is that the `ListView` is currently displayed as wider than 260 pixels since it will fill its entire cell. This can be solved by setting the max width of the `ListView`.

Comment: Using James_D answer for the descArea and Jonatan Stenbacka for the ListView both worked, thank you!

Comment: Updated with a couple of different solutions for the list box. Thanks @JonatanStenbacka for clarifying that.

Answer (score 1):

`GridPane` seems like a good way to do this, yes. First, I would put the labels and their displays in `HBox` controls instead of putting them in differents cells in the `Grid`. Then, to move the mana label up under the health label I would just put both controls in a `VBox` and then put that `VBox` in the cell.

```
HBox healthBox = new HBox(10);
healthBox.getChildren().addAll(healthLabel, healthDisplay);

HBox manaBox = new HBox(10);
manaBox.getChildren().addAll(manaLabel, manaDisplay); 

VBox box = new VBox(10);
box.getChildren().addAll(healthBox, manaBox);

GridPane.setConstraints(box, 1, 0);
```

To make sure that the `ListView` doesn't not fill its entire cell, you can set the maxWidth of the `ListView`:

`listView.setPrefWidth(260);
 listView.setMaxWidth(260);`